# Implementing multilingual portable windows form application using c#, visual studio enterprise 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

please i am working on a c# widows form application. the app is actually a word game which has both french and english parts. the app uses sqlite database with two tables, english_words and french_words which keep the words that are used in the game.

i want the app to behave in a way that when the player selects the english part, all the words given by the system should be read correctly using en-GB accent and when the user select the french part of the game, all the words provided by the system should be correctly read using the fr-FR accent and pronounctiation.

i have been working on it and till now everything is working perfectly except the pronouncers(**the words given by the system are read using default configurations of the system, hence a computer with french os installed on it reads french words correctly and reads the english words letter by letter, and vice versa**)...i've spent lot of time searching for solutions online but all i've seen and tried so far is not working as i want. i've even downloaded TTS packs from Microsoft website and installed them on my system but i can't get the intalled voices when i used the getinstalledvoices methos under **system.speech**...please is there any correct and clean solution to my issue? if yes, how do i implement and embed everything in my app so that it can be used on ervery targeted windows machine without issues or external installations...thanks

Comment: Take a look at [UWP Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-xaml-universal), if you want to expand compatibility to any platform (mac, android, windows) you can take a look a [Xamarin Forms](https://www.xamarin.com/forms) which are also built in to visual studio.

Comment: the game is a desktop application, not a mobile game

Comment: Both of those technologies can deploy to desktop.